# DrRacket's call/cc

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations

```
#lang racket

(let ((r (lambda (cont)
           (if (zero? (random 2))
               (+ 1000 6)
               (cont 6)))))
  (+ (* (+ (call/cc r) 3) 8)
     (* (+ (call/cc r) 3) 8)))
```

I have ran above code inside Racket IDE, and it give 3 different results
144, 16144, 8144.
I can understand why the code outputs **144**, and **16144**, but I am confused why it outputs **8144**

I am use DrRacket, version 8.11.1 under windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(random 2)` returns 0, `r` returns 1006, which then has 3 added to it (to get 1009) and is multiplied by 8, giving 8072. If it instead returns 1, `r` returns 6, which then has 3 added to it (to get 9) and is multiplied by 8, giving 72. Since `r` is called twice, each time returning either 3 or 1006, you get a number of possible results of summing the two values together:

| first r | second r | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 144 |
| 6 | 1006 | 8144 |
| 1006 | 6 | 8144 |
| 1006 | 1006 | 16144 |

---

There's no point I can see to using `call/cc` here; it has no impact on the code, which can equivalently be written

```lisp
(let ((r (lambda ()
           (if (zero? (random 2))
               (+ 1000 6)
               6))))
  (+ (* (+ (r) 3) 8)
     (* (+ (r) 3) 8)))
```

Comment: this code is used to help me understand call/cc related concept.I think I was confused  because of I am not clear about call/cc's context.